# Prestashop Web Services API - React Native

Tags: react-native, prestashop

I'm trying to make a query to receive data from the database with PrestaShop API (with react native ). I read the documentation of this and tried to adjust the given code to what I need. I created my API key in PrestaShop BO and set the authorization too "All", but I always got an error 400. When I print the response, I got this:

[image]

There's my code:

```js
import {encode} from "base-64";
import parser from "fast-xml-parser";

export async function getProductsMatching() {
  const apiKey = "PS_API_KEY";
  const authorizationKey = encode(apiKey + ":");
  const url = "https://www.example.com/api/v1/addresses?display=full";

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic " + authorizationKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Erreur lors de la récupération des données");
      }
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((xmlData) => {
      const jsonData = parser.parse(xmlData);
      console.log("Parsed Data:", jsonData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Erreur ici", error);
    });
}
```

If someone could explain me why I got an error 400..

Comment: I don't know about your issue exactly. Maybe you could improuve your post by replacing the screenshot by the actual json code block. Other than that, PrestaShop 1.6.1.19 is terribly outdated (2018) and potentially at risk of being compromised (which can create terrible outcomes for a WebShop and its customers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things and deleted the "/v1/" in the url made the script worked :

```js
const url = "https://www.example.com/api/products";

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorizationKey}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
```

Comment: We don't version WS in PrestaShop, so yes, it wasn't needed :D